# React Router Required context `router` was not specified in `Link`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get routing working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've been fighting this one for too long :(

Blog.js fails to render because of the error below.

Here is the error:

***Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router` was not specified in `Link`. Check the render method of `BlogList`.
bundle.js:26589 Warning: owner-based and parent-based contexts differ (values: `undefined` vs `function (props, context) {
      // This constructor is overridden by mocks. The argument is used***

What I expect to happen:

When the blog page(Blog.js) renders it will have a list of articles. When the user clicks on an article they are directed to : http://site/blog/articleId (BlogView.js)

Code:

Main.js

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation,function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('startApp'));
});
```

App.js

```
 var App = React.createClass({
    render : function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <RouteHandler />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Router:

```
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>
    <Route name="home" path="/home" handler={Home}/>
    <Route name="blog" path="/blog" handler={Blog}/>
    <Route name="blogView" path="/blog/:id" handler={BV}/>
    <Route name="about" path="/about" handler={About}/>
</Route>
```

Components: 
Blog.js:

```
render: function () {

    return (

        <div className="container-fluid">
            <BlogList blogEntries = {this.state.blogEntries} rawMarkup={this.state.rawMarkup}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

BlogList.js:
return (

```
        <div className="container-fluid" style={{
                paddingTop: '10px'
        }}>

            <div style={{
                paddingLeft: '100px',
                paddingRight : '100px'
            }}>
                <div style={{
                backgroundColor : 'white',
                boxShadow: '10px 10px 5px #888888',
                border: '2px solid black'
              }}>
                    <Link to="blogView" className="text-center">test </Link>

                    <div className="text-center">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: What require statements do you have at the top of BlogList.js?

Comment: You may need to add `contextTypes` to pull in `router` on the component context.

Answer (score 0):

What is the id of your parent "div" in index.html?

It should be

```
  <div id="startApp">
  </div>
```

However if you followed the course by Corey House "[Building Applications with React and Flux](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/discussion/react-flux-building-applications)", i believe the parent div in index.html should be

```
<div id="app">
</div>
```

If that's the case then your Main.js should be

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Notice the 'app' instead of 'startApp'.